# Upgrading rails on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, updating

I know the question to this is probably very straight forward, but Im a bit new to rails, so please bear with me. I have had rails version 5.1.5 on my Mac and I need to update rails to version 5.1.6 and I'm not able for the life of me to do that.

I tried

```
 `sudo gem install rails -v 5.1.6`
```

but this gives the error 
**ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.**

Using `gem list` gives that I have

**rails (5.1.5, 5.1.4)**

I also tried `bundle update rails`

I keep getting **Could not locate Gemfile**

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Don't do anything with the software MacOS gives you. Install RVM and use that to install a real Ruby. You'll need Xcode to build it. [rvm.io](https://rvm.io)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gem` is the native package manager for Ruby.

Bundler (`bundle`) is a gem to manage bundles of gems via a `Gemfile`.

I recommend you use a version manager for Ruby like rvm, rbenv or chruby and also install xcode and the commandline-tools package of xcode. Some gems have dependencies written in C that need to be configured and compiled, all of that and some more comes with xcode.